# Python Pandas - groupby conditional on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, which are identical in terms of size (rows/date index and columns/firms). What I want to do now is to calculate timeseries statistics for the observations in Dataframe1 based on the logic contained in Dataframe2. For example, I want to calulcate the timeseries average observation (Dataframe1) based on a rank (Dataframe2)

So some sort of a groupby-procedure except the fact that I use a second dataframe for the condition.

Glad for any input as I was not able to find a similar problem!

```
Dataframe1
----------------------------------
            A      B      C      D      E      F       G      H             
31.12.2009  30     66     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     393    57     
01.01.2010  30     66     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     393    57   
04.01.2010  31     66     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     404    57     
05.01.2010  33     66     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     400    58    
06.01.2010  33     66     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     400    58   


Dataframe2
----------------------------------
            A      B      C      D      E      F       G      H            
31.12.2009  1.0    2.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     2.0    1.0     
01.01.2010  1.0    2.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     2.0    1.0   
04.01.2010  1.0    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     2.0    2.0     
05.01.2010  1.0    2.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     1.0    2.0    
06.01.2010  2.0    2.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     1.0    1.0  


Desired output
----------------------------------
            1.0     2.0            
31.12.2009  43.5    229.5     
01.01.2010  43.5    229.5   
04.01.2010  48.5    230.5       
05.01.2010  216.5   62.0        
06.01.2010  229.0   49.5
```

Comment: one way to do it is to temporarily add the column needed for the condition to the dataframe 1

Comment: How do you get 43.5 from 30 and 66 with 1 and 2?

Comment: The 43.5 is the mean of 30 and 57. I want to calculate the mean when the observation meet the same condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing each value one at a time:

(1)

```
df1.where(df2 == 1).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
31.12.2009     43.5
01.01.2010     43.5
04.01.2010     48.5
05.01.2010    216.5
06.01.2010    229.0
```

(2)

```
df1.where(df2 == 2).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
31.12.2009    229.5
01.01.2010    229.5
04.01.2010    230.5
05.01.2010     62.0
06.01.2010     49.5
```

Combining into a your desired output:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'1':df1.where(df2 == 1).mean(axis=1),
                       '2':df1.where(df2 == 2).mean(axis=1)})
                1      2
31.12.2009   43.5  229.5
01.01.2010   43.5  229.5
04.01.2010   48.5  230.5
05.01.2010  216.5   62.0
06.01.2010  229.0   49.5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create the result dataframe. Each column is generated using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to replace values in `df1` 
 by nan when the specific value is not met in `df2`, to be able to use [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) over axis=1 for each [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) value of `df2`

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame({col: df1.where(df2.eq(col)).mean(1) for col in df2.stack().unique()})
print (df_res)
              1.0    2.0
31.12.2009   43.5  229.5
01.01.2010   43.5  229.5
04.01.2010   48.5  230.5
05.01.2010  216.5   62.0
06.01.2010  229.0   49.5
```

Comment: Just a quick follow on question: how to expand the code if I want to use multiple conditions (= one dataframe per condition)?

Comment: @rentec it depends what you mean by multiple conditions but I guess the best would be to create a list of condition `l_cond` and then replace in the loop. so something like in the current case: `l_cond = [df2.eq(1), df2.eq(2)]` and then `pd.DataFrame({'cond_{}'.format(i): df1.where(cond).mean(1) for i, cond in enumerate(l_cond)})` or something like this